# Show only 'today' and future dates in calendar picker. No dates in past

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having a Date field `myDatefield__c`. I'm accessing it in VF page.

So, is there any way, so that I can disable the old dates.

For example: If I click on the date field, when calender pop up will come, then I can see only today's date and future dates.Past dates and months will be disabled.

Comment: Seek this post it could be of helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186429/how-to-disable-all-previous-dates-on-the-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Bob Buzzard published a great blog post about using a utility called JSCalendar in conjunction with a visualforce page.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-date-picker.html